# Enforcing same argument list using generic in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints

I'm trying to create a typescript enforcer over `EventEmitter`. My goal is to create a emitter with `addListener`, `removeListener` and `emit` methods that will break on compiler time if I pass a invalid event or even if I pass a function that doesn't match with event signature (args and return).

For this to be possible, I'll need a Map interface (some interface with a list of functions) an example of this can be seen on type native `GlobalEventHandlersEventMap` in:

lib.dom.d.ts

```
//...
interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
  "abort": UIEvent;
  "animationcancel": AnimationEvent;
  "animationend": AnimationEvent;
  "animationiteration": AnimationEvent;
  //...
```

So far I got the first two methods right:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

// A simple mapping interface
interface SomeMap {
  greeting: (message: string) => void;
}

// This generalization of function is necessary to track
// the list of arguments and result types.
interface GFunc<TArgs extends any[] = any[], TResult = any> {
  (...args: TArgs): TResult;
}

// This is a advanced type to mask the EventEmitter class
interface AdvEventEmitter<T extends { [K in keyof T]: GFunc }> {
  addListener<K extends keyof T>(event: K, listener: T[K]): void;
  removeListener<K extends keyof T>(event: K, listener: T[K]): void;
}

const emitter: AdvEventEmitter<SomeMap> = new EventEmitter();

emitter.addListener('greeting', msg => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

In the code above, `AdvEventEmitter` interface is capable to enforce constraint on the first parameter:

```
emitter.addListener('something_else', () => {});
```

> `Msg: Argument of type '"something_else"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"greeting"'.`

And even enforce types and quantity of arguments in the second parameter:

```
emitter.addListener('greeting', (m1, m2) => {
  console.log(m1, m2);
});
```

> `Msg: Argument of type '(m1: any, m2: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of`
> `type '(message: string) => void'.`

Great.

Now **the problem is** the `emit` method.

I'm trying something like this:

```
interface AdvEventEmitter<T extends { [K in keyof T]: GFunc }> {
  // ...
  emit<K extends keyof T, TArgs extends any[] = any[]>(event: K, ...args: TArgs): void;
}
```

the arg `event` is validated correctly (as expected), but the `args` just a generic list of any. I'm don't know how to connect `TArgs` constraints with `K` constraints.

Is there a way to enforce this constrain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the parameters of the `K` function  from `T`. You can do this using the predefined `Parameters` conditional type:

```
interface AdvEventEmitter<T extends { [K in keyof T]: GFunc }> {
  emit<K extends keyof T>(event: K, ...args: Parameters<T[K]>): void;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=44&ssc=2&pln=41&pc=1#code/PTB04KASwOwFwKYCcBmBDAxggBAcQDYD2ARmvgKIBuC8AEmjACb7IDOVNcAsmgA7YBvCNhHYARGmKEkcMQC5sAVQCSHeAG5hoiTCgBbNHCiEYGBlnzzsAQV0GjJtXE2jxDfYeMwajK7Y8OME4u2u72XlCISJ4mfnYxQdQaWiIg4KAQAL7QerzScILYTuR6kVHYmdgoSIR64ghJcKximhAgNtis+rws2Aa8vLAA5tiwUehY0PDIEzgAyrUIPPxCIkNICAhGMEMKABR6CKysaEMICqxwSMMAlNgAvAB82JSEUIya2W3A2AAqABZQVjYM7eaL4KAALwS2EIKCqAFdTIFRsDvFhjmgkABPbBwQh46IYADW3zx-xwEMusPhWKGCMO8GBDEY2A2rAR+AKcGxvCOGTGM0wOFwADEkRgADy-axIIbAhAAD0QTGZMGxAG0ALoPbAMTVagA0fwASkdOQV7nr1c9Vtg9uk6awFDK5awbi6zRyuZ8IGSAUDUXq9YxKOYEKyeXy8QSDKxieScMVSnByhh8GhjlNxsKbKHk2VkNLsEqVYxgQJsBqANKjGDYYkIbFwv5ahRiiUVW1aNCMRgAGSBKqLtdLPmBjeb8N+jz2DU4Cmrxqpw6QLprWo9LzeHy0Gz0hGog8uNBHJeV44bTZbM7njUXy6Hp7Xfw3W9e719EAwJmpCBTUQKNY+aNCUhZIJKCyHMszxWt4ADuRSgQByB7DcrT-uBoC9gOT5gnsADk6ybNsQwEcaeisCMTyCFoP4wKwhAsKARBDAcVHoVknF+phqbINhfbHquhGMYccCAjsAD6CD4KwCDkfadw0QImTcRAvFRAJuEnvhREbFswwKQcACMFEAExKd2Ij0YxzGsSZ5mcaprSCqgubAZQBZ8RBvznmWFZVrWsBXlOrbtuKphdrRIi8ZKo4XqqIU3rO87wA+2COm6CgAApYmgYlsNKG6PO+O5fhp-G8XsYjEQZOxiMaYhiDcQA)